# vite failed to load config from vite.config.js,

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vite

I created a new vue app by doing these (*according to vue docs*)

1. `npm init vue@latest`
2. `npm install`

Then I try to run `npm run dev`.Then this happened.

[image]

**My environments are these**

- OS => Ubuntu
- Node version => 18.7.0
- npm version => 8.15.0

**My package.json**

```
{
  "name": "vue-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 4173"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.37"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.1",
    "vite": "^3.0.4"
  }
}
```

**My vite.config.js**

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

I have been searching for a while now but no avail.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just try to delete `node_modules`, and install again

Comment: @MichalLevý I tried it a lot of times,but still the same error,also changed node version back and forth but still the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.
The problem was because of the **package.json** file conflict.
**Vite** is using the wrong **package.json** file located in the Project's parent directory instead of project's own **package.json** file.Like this -

- **~/package.json** ( wrong file )
- **~/Projects/VueProject/package.json** ( correct file )

So delete the wrong file and the problem will be fixed.

Thanks to this github issue answer  [package.json:1:0: error: Unexpected end of file](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2404#issuecomment-793166114)

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me too.

I apparently made a package-lock.json with an older version of npm.

Just letting people know that this could also be causing the same issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here as well. It seems that the output would optimize for browser execution and modules like "path, fs and all so on" do not exist for the browser. Which makes sense, because it's part of nodejs itself. It can't work within a browser. That's my assumption so far.

Take a look at the various solutions to understand why I made those assumptions.

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/6849
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/7821#issuecomment-1142328698

https://github.com/marcofugaro/browserslist-to-esbuild
https://esbuild.github.io/getting-started/

Given this information, I prefer a simpler solution to prevent a build failure with Vite as the bundler.

**Configure rollupOptions**

I think the simplest solution is to define externals.
https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#external

```js
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [],
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
            name: 'myLib',
            fileName: 'myLib',
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            external: [/^node:\w+/], // <-- ignores all 'node:*'
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried all means but what solved was the needed to update nodejs on pc, after update to make sure that have the updated version by using the cmd> *node -v* in the terminal or command prompt.

Sometimes we have more than one working installation of nodejs...